# Silverlight MessageBox DelayedExecute?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

```
Dim msg As MessageBox
msg.DelayedExecute(milliseconds As integer, Method As System.Action)
```

### Question

Can you please help me understand what the above method is? I cannot find this on google and it is not present in msdn!  or am i missing something?

Comment: Where have you got the code from?  The Silverlight MessageBox does not have such a method.  Perhaps it is an extension method from a Third-party.